# Google Closure: Passing 'this' into window.setInterval

Tags: javascript, closures, google-closure-compiler, google-closure, google-closure-library

I have a model js file which looks like

```
goog.provide('model.ErrorLogger');
/**
 * @constructor
 */
model.ErrorLogger = function() {
    window.onerror = goog.bind(this.errorHandler, this);
    this.doInitialSend();

};
goog.addSingletonGetter(model.ErrorLogger);

model.ErrorLogger.prototype.ws_ErrLgr_config = true;

model.ErrorLogger.prototype.doInitialSend = function(){
    if (this.ws_ErrLgr_config){
        window.setInterval(this.sendReport, this.ws_ErrLgr_config);
    }   

};

model.ErrorLogger.prototype.sendReport = function(){
    // the value of 'this' needs to be of the ErrorLogger model and not windows
    if (!this.ws_ErrLgr_config || this.stopped) {
          //some more code here
    }
}
```

In the constructor I call the doInitialSend function which set the window.setInterval. Now in the sendReport function the the value of 'this' is not correct. How to correctly pass 'this' to get the correct value instead of getting window's this. 
I tried storing the the value of this in a reference but that didn't work either. For example

```
var that = this;
window.setInterval(that.sendReport, that.ws_ErrLgr_config);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idiomatic way to do this in Google Closure is using `goog.bind`, with the advantage that it's guaranteed it's always going to work. Plus it will use `Function.prototype.bind()` under the hood when that is available.

In that case the solution will be:

```
myIntervalInMilliseconds = 1000; // One second.
window.setInterval(goog.bind(this.sendReport, this), myIntervalInMilliseconds);
```

Using `that = this` works, but requires you to explicitly wrap your function within another one to capture `that` as `this` within the desired function.

It's much better using `Function.prototype.bind()` for that, as pointed out in the other answers. However this won't work if you care to support older browsers (IE < 9).

---

PS: Another issue in your code is that it is using `this.ws_ErrLgr_config` as the interval, which is set to `true` in the prototype. This is incorrect, you should pick a number to represent your interval.

Comment: `goog.bind` is just a pollyfill for `Function.prototype.bind`. If the browser supports native function binding, `goog.bind` will use it.

Comment: This is really great. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
var that = this;
window.setInterval(function() {
    that.sendReport()
}, this.ws_ErrLgr_config.ReportInterval);
```

That way you can call sendReport in the correct context, also this works:

```
 window.setInterval(this.sendReport.bind(this), this.ws_ErrLgr_config.ReportInterval);
```

The reason why `window.setInterval(that.sendReport, this.ws_ErrLgr_config.ReportInterval)` doesn't work is because Javascript is pass-by-value. The above statement is the equivalent to:

```
window.setInterval(function(){
    // the value of 'this' needs to be of the ErrorLogger model and not windows
    if (!this.ws_ErrLgr_config || this.stopped) {
          //some more code here
    }
}, this.ws_ErrLgr_config.ReportInterval);
```

By using the .bind() keyword or wrapping it in another function and then refering to a `that`from the outerscope, you can call the function in the desired scope.

Comment: cool that works. but how does putting an extra function solve this ?

Comment: `window.setInterval(that.sendReport, ...)` points to the sendReport function in the global scope, because javascript is pass by value. So wrapping it in another function and then calling `that.sendReport();` will call it in the correct context.

Answer (score 0):

Or this:

```
window.setInterval((function() {
    this.sendReport();
}).bind(this), this.ws_ErrLgr_config.ReportInterval);
```

Comment: Yes, that works too. Shorter would be: `this.sendReport.bind(this)`. But now you forgot the interval. `this.ws_ErrLgr_config.ReportInterval`

Comment: You're right, my fault. The shorter version is even better. Should I change the post?

Comment: It's fine, the more the merrier. It's always interesting to see different approaches to solve an issue.